# Rails: Form Tag Skipping Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot explain why, but somehow my form_tag form is skipping streight to my view and completely bypassing my controller action.

This is my form_tag:

```
<%=form_tag url_for(:controller=>"orders", :action=>"finalize_order"), :method=>'post' do%>
<%=hidden_field_tag "cc_id_selection"%>
<%=hidden_field_tag "address_id_selection"%>   
<%=submit_tag "Checkout", :class=>"btn btn-primary"%>
<%end%>
```

And here is my controller action:

```
def finalize_order
  @selected_user_card_id = UserCard.find(params[:cc_id_selection])
  begin #in case they chose pickup
    @selected_address = Address.find(params[:address_id_selection])
  rescue
    @selected_address = params[:address_id_selection] #we can add options besides pickup if we'd like
  end
end
```

This is what is logged in my console (with some ip stuff taken out) I tried putting a trace in the controller and don't see any sign of it:

```
Started POST "/finalize_order"  Processing by OrdersController#finalize_order as HTML
```

I see at the bottom of the error page that the two params were successfully posted. Yet when I submit I get error in the next view indicating no param was instantiated in the controller. Even stranger, when I comment out the action I get the same exact results! I even tried using a route, anf get the same results. It seems I am completely skipping the action and going streight to the view. What might cause this bug?

Comment: Please post your routes file, and how do you know that your code bypasses the controller method. Have you inserted any `puts` statements in that method?

Comment: Other thing: You aren't passing anything in `cc_id_selection` and `address_id_select`.

Comment: I know that I am bypassing the action because when I comment it out nothing scary happens (ERROR: no action, etc).

Comment: If the action isn't there, it'll just open the view.  What do the logs show?  Are you able to find a UserCard in the db?

Comment: As far as the values, those are inputted with javascript which I didn't include because it is not relevant to the question. I know the params are being passed because they're displayed at the bottom of the error page, as noted in the question.

Comment: @Swards thanks I didn't know that, so maybe the error is with the assignments? Do you see anything wrong with them?

Comment: Add a `raise @selected_user_card_id.inspect` right after it's instantiated

Comment: Throws an exception and prints the string value of the @selected_user_card_id object.  As Arslan suggested, `puts` to stdout would also work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97480/discussion-between-ester-lin-and-swards).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've accidentally made your `finalize_order` method *private* in your controller. If it's a private method, it won't be called, and the view will be rendered directly. This is a little-known feature of Rails - the action doesn't actually have to exist.

If the method is private, (the `private` keyword will be above it in the controller somewhere) then move the action to above the keyword to make it public.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what sevenseacat suggested, but the actual problem is that I accidentally had two finalize_order methods. I guess rails couldn't decide which one to run, so it ran neither.